# Split a file by a certain keyword into a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a few files and inside each file there are many "documents" identified by the HTML tag:

```
<DOC myid="1">
...some text here...
</DOC>

<DOC myid="2">
...some text here...
</DOC>
//etc...
```

So each "DOC" element is considered a document.

And in each file there are hundreds of these DOC "documents" each identifiable by their myid="n", where n = 1,2,3...

My question is simply how can i split these files by this tag and assign the contents to a Python list? (each element in my list would have an id = myid of a DOC document

Answer (score 0):

Its better you use LXML parser using beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

content = []
myResult = []

with open("file.xml","r") as f:
  content = f.readlines()
  content = "".join(content)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
  
myDocs = soup.find_all("DOC")
for x in myDocs:
  myResult.apend(x.text)
```

Before this install them use it in Command prompt/terminal to install bs4 and lxml:

```
pip install bs4 lxml
```

Comment: But do i have to use lxml? What if my files are not xml type?

Comment: why don't you do `content = f.read()` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "lxml")`

Comment: @Uriel it looks like XML. And never use regex to parse HTML/XML. And also extension dont seem to matter here